# Assigning value to rowData but Array giving length 0 - Ag-grid

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid-angular

I have data with a specific format given below, I have stored the data in **this.list**
But I have to assign this.list to a variable i.e., **rowData** but It is showing array lenght 0 while list have data. Refer images for more clarity about question.

[Response of list is showing here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fis8d.png) 
[Assigning data to rowData but getting nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5wPh.png)

JSON Data Format is-

```
[
  {
    group: 'Group A',
    participants: [
      {
        group: 'Menu',
        enable: 'Michael Phelps',
        menuType: '2008',
        url: 'United States',
        participants: [
          {
            group: 'Menu.1',
            enable: 'Michael Phelps',
            menuType: '2008',
            url: 'United States'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        group: 'Menu2',
        enable: 'Michael Phelps',
        menuType: '2008',
        url: 'United States'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    group: 'Group A',
    participants: [
      {
        group: 'Menu',
        enable: 'Michael Phelps',
        menuType: '2008',
        url: 'United States',
        participants: [
          {
            group: 'Menu.1',
            enable: 'Michael Phelps',
            menuType: '2008',
            url: 'United States'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        group: 'Menu2',
        enable: 'Michael Phelps',
        menuType: '2008',
        url: 'United States'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: It is showing length zero because the statement might not be interpreted yet. What happens when you use `this.rowData` somewhere later in the component? Is it still showing length zero?

Comment: No, this.rowData is showing same if we use anywhere.

Comment: Then could you please post the component code?

Comment: Yes, done. Thank you for your advice. I used to declare rowData:any and then this.rowData= this.list in a function & it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Declaration

```
rowData:any
```

Calling it in function.
Let's consider your response is in **res**

```
this.rowData= res ;
```